# Bot Response based on user session using botframework (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, botframework, ibm-watson

How to send bot response based on user session in NodeJS.

I have created a sample NodeJS application using botframework and connecting to IBM watson to process the user query to get the appropriate response and sending back the response with 10secs delay.

I have generate the ngrok URL and configured it bot framework for web channel. When i test this in mutipl browsers simulataneously , i am getting the same response for all , not based on the user session and user request.

It's giving the latest request processed response to everyuser. I have copied the sample nodejs code below.

Can someone please look into my code and suggest me on how to send the response based on user session/conversationID?

```js
NodeJS sample code :

'use strict';

var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var Conversation = require('watson-developer-cloud/conversation/v1'); 
require('dotenv').config({silent: true});

var server = restify.createServer();

var contexts = { CandidateID : "89798" , Location : "USA"  }
var workspace= 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

let name,id,message,addr,watson;
var savedAddress;

server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

// Create the service wrapper
var conversation = new Conversation({
    username: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    password: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api',
    version_date: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

// setup bot credentials
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
  appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  appPassword: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector,);

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

// root dialog
bot.dialog('/', function (session, args) {
 
    name = session.message.user.name;
 id = session.message.user.id;
 message = session.message.text;
 savedAddress = session.message.address;
   
    var payload = {
        workspace_id: workspace,
        context: contexts,
        input: {
            text: session.message.text
        }
    };
 
    var conversationContext = {
        workspaceId: workspace,
        watsonContext: contexts
    };

    if (!conversationContext) {
        conversationContext = {};
    }

    payload.context = conversationContext.watsonContext;
  
    conversation.message(payload, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            session.send(err);
        } else {   
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));          
            conversationContext.watsonContext = response.context;
   watson = response.output.text;
        }
    }); 
  
 console.log(message);
  
 setTimeout(() => {
  startProactiveDialog(savedAddress);
 }, 10000);
});

// handle the proactive initiated dialog
bot.dialog('/survey', function (session, args, next) {
  if (session.message.text === "done") {
    session.send("Great, back to the original conversation");
    session.endDialog();
  } else {
   session.send(id + ' ' + watson);
  }
});

// initiate a dialog proactively 
function startProactiveDialog(address) {
  bot.beginDialog(address, "*:/survey");
}
```

Comment: Hi @ganeshkumar, is there any update?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure it passes back and forth all of the system context for that user's session. Our botkit middleware essentially does this for you.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware

Answer (score 0):

It looks like  that you are leveraging the sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages/startNewDialog Sending a dialog-based proactive message to specific user.

The sample is just for reference, it only saves the latest conversion at it only declare one variable `savedAddress`, each time the new user comes in, the new seession address will assign to `savedAddress` and cover the old value.

You can try to define an object to save user addresses for quick test:

```
var savedAddress = {};
bot.dialog('/', function (session, args) {

  savedAddress[session.message.address.id] = session.message.address;

  var message = 'Hey there, I\'m going to interrupt our conversation and start a survey in a few seconds.';
  session.send(message);

  message = 'You can also make me send a message by accessing: ';
  message += 'http://localhost:' + server.address().port + '/api/CustomWebApi';
  session.send(message);

  setTimeout(() => {
    startProactiveDialog(savedAddress[session.message.address.id]);
  }, 5000);
});
```

For production stage, you can leverage Redis or some other cache storage to store this address list.

Hope it helps.